# Chained method from string

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, method-chaining

In a script project associated with a Google spreadsheet, I want to write a function that extracts data from a range of cells. There are multiple [extraction methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) corresponding to different data types, i.e. `getValues`, `getBackgrounds` etc.

The usual way of calling these would be:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('mysheet')
var A1 = 'A1:A2'
var values = sheet.getRange(A1).getValues()
```

However, this happens inside a function, and I want to let the user determine the extraction method in the function call like so:

```
var r = myfunction(arg1, arg2, extractionMethod = 'getValues')
```

So I need to be able to use `extractionMethod` (i.e. the string that it contains) to call the method.

I tried:

```
var values = sheet.getRange(A1).window[extractionMethod]
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property "getValues" from undefined. (line 31, file "fun")

I also tried

```
var values = sheet.getRange(A1)[extractionMethod]
```

But then `Logger.log(values)` just gives

> [16-10-01 04:09:15:014 PDT] function getBackgrounds() {/*
>   */}

**What I want to achieve:** A function call that uses the string `'getValues'` (or another valid method name) and is equivalent to calling, for example

```
var values = sheet.getRange(A1).getValues()
```

Comment: this is a server side script there is no "window" here

Comment: Good to know, @Harold. Is there a server-side equivalent?

Comment: What is the broader context?  What is the starting point?  What is the desired end result?

Comment: You need to use parentheses to call a method. `var values = sheet.getRange(A1)[methodName]()`

Comment: @SandyGood I tried to clarify a bit. Let me know if this is not enough.

Comment: @SpiderPig oh, I need to put the parenteses *after* the brackets! Well, live and learn... this works, would you be so kind and make it an answer - it seems trivial, but maybe if you elaborate a little bit, people would find it useful? (And this could be marked as solved then...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With brackets you can access the properties of an object.
If e.g. you define an object like this:

```
var obj = {
  x: 1,
  m: function() {
    return this.x * 2;
  }
};
```

you can get `x` with `obj.x` or with `obj['x']`.
`obj['m']` will give you the method `m` and if you want to call `m` you need to add parentheses i.e. `obj.m()` or `obj['m']()`.